# passing jQuery IDs as parameters a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Javascript

```
function changeInitial(init,alter)
{   
<!--alert(alter);-->

init.parent().hide();
alter.parent().show();
}
```

---

### Html

```
<div class="form_item">
   <div class="form_label">
         <label>Account</label>
   </div>
   <span id="new_ac">
       <input type="text"/>
       <a id="create_ac" onclick ='changeInitial($("#create_ac, #select_ac"));'>
           Select Existing Account
       </a>
   </span>
   <span id="existing_ac">
       <select>
         <option>Select an account</option>
         <option>Customer</option>
         <option>Competitor</option>
         <option>Investor</option>
         <option>Partner</option>
         <option>Reseller</option>
         <option>Supplier</option>
       </select>
       <a id="select_ac">Create new Account</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

---

Firebug keeps telling me that "alter" is undefined. Please is there something I am missing? "init" is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure JavaScript can interpret your JQuery selection as two parameters in "changeInitial". It has two Parameters but you only send one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "changeInitial(...)" call in your HTML, change to this:

```
onclick='changeInitial($("#create_ac"), $("#select_ac"));'
```

The way you are doing it, you are only specifying a single parameter.

Comment: Its suppose to be a toggle action though, so is there an proper way to  reverse the action. i.e when #select_ac becomes visible.

Comment: @Shoppyonline - Inside the `changeInitial` function, you could check to see which button is visible by using `init.parent().is(":visible")`, and if `init` is invisible, show `init`, and hide `alter`, and if `init` is visible, hide `init` and show `alter`

Comment: @Karl Nicoll - Thank you. Yes that makes a lot of sense but I just switched the IDs in the html and that worked too. Okay another question, how do I make the #select_ac's parent invisible on page load without having to specify $("#existing_ac").hide(); (ie #select_ac parent)

Comment: @Shoppyonline - You could do this by using the JQuery `$(document).ready();` function. For example: `$(document).ready(function() { $("#select_ac").parent().hide(); });`.

Comment: Yes @aSeptik gives a very good solution below. Using classes is a brilliant idea and I can also use the function for multiple element-pair instances. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
onclick ='changeInitial($("#create_ac"),$("#select_ac"));'
```

otherwise it's just one jquery object.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Works fine. You missed a " after "#create_ac.

Comment: Its suppose to be a toggle action though, so is there an proper way to reverse the action. i.e when #select_ac becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using onclick?

Use jquery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#create_ac').click(function(){
        changeInitial($("#create_ac"), $('#select_ac'));
    });
});

   function changeInitial(init,alter)
{   
    <!--alert(alter);-->

    init.parent().hide();
    alter.parent().show();
}
```

check out my example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/qqksd/

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#create_ac').click(function(){
        changeInitial($("#create_ac"), $('#select_ac'));
    });
    $('#select_ac').click(function(){
        changeInitial($("#select_ac"), $('#create_ac'));
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/qqksd/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        changeInitial($(this).attr('id'), $('#select_ac'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to use this function for other elements. This the only way I thought about that allows me to select a particular ID and manipulate it. Its suppose to be a toggle action though, so you can help me figure out how to reverse the action. i.e when #select_ac becomes visible.

Comment: Yep! :) Thats it alright! But how do I make the IDs dynamic because multiple pair elements need to use this function.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ehumu4/4 *(Updated)*

```
$(function(){
  $('span a').click(function(){ //work with pairs just like an accordion
    $(this).parent(':visible').hide().siblings().show();
  });
});
```

---

```
<!-- you should use classe's instead of id's -->
<span><a href="#" class="select_ac">Create new Account</a></span>
<span><a href="#" class="create_ac">Select Existing Account</a></span>
```

---

```
 .existing_ac {display:none } /* hidden at page load */
```

Comment: @aSeptik Good solution. I need to use this function for any pair of elements. See conversation with @Karl Nicoll above.

Comment: Thanks @aSeptik. Using classes makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @Shoppyonline: it is not just a matter of easier, but a standard to accomplish, you can't have duplicate id's in your page. id's must be unique; so, if you need to have many pairs, the way to go is using classes and also use just one function instead of multiple inline onlick events. hope this help.

Comment: @Shoppyonline and @aSeptik. This is a good solution, I'd suggest changing the answer from mine to this. Do bear in mind though that setting the `.existing_ac` class to `display:none;` in CSS will not allow user's to "select existing account" if they have JavaScript disabled because the code to show the elements won't run, if that needs consideration. I'd recommend still hiding all hidden elements in JavaScript.

Comment: Excellent @aSeptik. @Karl Nicoll a very valid recommendation. Are there people in this world that still have JavaScript disabled??

Comment: @Shoppyonline: javascript can be disabled for very different reasons, but this is just a normal behaviour that could happen when building web apps. if your app make use of javascript be sure to include `<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>`

Comment: @aSeptik I'll remember that from now on.